# How to generate Allure report using cucumber and JUnit?

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, allure, cucumber-java

I am trying to create allure report using cucumber + Junit but allure-result folder is not getting created. Though test cases are getting passed successfully just I want to create allure-result folder which is not getting created. Requesting you suggestions.[This is my project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW1Xt.png)

Step Defination File:

```
public class CustomerInfoVerification {

@Given("^user is already on home Page$")
public void user_is_already_on_home_Page() throws Throwable {
    System.out.print(" thid is Given");
}

@When("^click on Pattinson, Robert provider$")
public void click_on_Pattinson_Robert_provider() throws Throwable {
    System.out.print("  thid is When");
}

@Then("^user verifies unm and password$")
public void userVerifiesGeography() throws Throwable {
    System.out.print(" thid is Then");

}
```

}

Feature File:

Feature:  Rule management module

Scenario: Provider information module

Given user is already on home Page

When click on Pattinson, Robert provider

Then user verifies unm and password

Image for [POM.xml[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kpg4.png) POM.xml
[POM.xml fil`enter code here`es image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAXzZ.png)

Comment: test Runner File:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:featureFile/clinicRule.feature" },
glue = { "stepDefination" },
monochrome = true,
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-reports",
  "json:target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json","rerun:target/failed_scenarios.txt" })
public class TestRunner {
}